Временный бан на Disnake
=
У меня есть база данных и команда "/ban". В базе данных хранится id случая, ник забаненного, модератор, дата бана, срок бана, досрочное снятие (булево). Мне необходимо сделать как-то ежеминутную проверку всех записей из базы данных, и, если дата бана + срок бана больше, чем время нынче, то пользователь снимается с бана. Как реализовать эту механику?

ну советую добавить в базу данных ещё столбец когда бан закончится так удобнее будет
добавляешь после запуска бота по токену(ну или где надо в функцие) while и в нём time.sleep(60) из модуля time, затем прогоняешься по базе данных с условием, что дата разбана совпадает с datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M") из модуля datetime и разбаниваешь. надеюсь помог, я сам не сильно шарю

Когда бан закончится, это сумма времени выдачи и срока действия : )

Если while, то бот и будет работать только в цикле while, а команды и пр. работать не будут

не, просто после запуска токена бот работает а вайл тоже работает отдельно

То есть, предлагаете поставить цикл while после bot.run()?

Нет, bot.run() это тоже цикл, из-за чего while цикл игнорируется до завершения bot.run()
